# Meaning of open (and closed) subgroup

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Cassels and Froehlich's ANT, I met with the following statement:

> p. 5: The additive group of $K$ is the union of open (and hence closed) subgroups $\mathfrak p^n$ ($n\in \Bbb Z$), whose intersection is zero.

Here $\mathfrak p$ is the prime ideal associated to a valuation on $K$. Since C&F didn't talk about topology up to this moment, I am not sure what the adjectives open and closed could mean. And even if they have a topological meaning, why does openness imply closedness? And why is the additive group of $K$ a union of only these subgroups? If we pick $\Bbb Q$ with the 5-adic valuation, for example, we still have many elements which do not lie in $(5)^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valution associated with $\mathfrak p$ defines a metric and hence a topology on $K$. And, yes, in this sense the subgroups considered are both open and closed. Saying "and hence" is indeed a bit strange though if the topological notions have not been investigated a bit before ...

For your last question: Note that $\mathfrak p^n$ is considered with $n\in\mathbb Z$, not merely $\mathbb n\in \mathbb N_0$.

Answer (score 2):

In a topological group, an open subgroup is also necessarily closed.
(Each coset is open, hence the union of all the non-identity cosets is open, and hence the subgroup itself, being their complement, is closed.)